# Generated Query with multiple SubSelect from Zend Framework 2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, subquery

I have been battling an issue with Zend Framework 2.

This function creates as many subselections as are needed to filter my results.

```
public function getResponsesByFilterArray($filter_array)
{
    $filter_array_count = 0;
    $limit = 100;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(
            function (\Zend\Db\Sql\Select $select) use($limit, $filter_array)
            {
                foreach($filter_array as $filter_model)
                {
                    $filter_array_count++;

                    $subselect = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
                    $subselect->from('question_responses');
                    $subselect->where(array('question_id' => $filter_model->question_id));

                    switch($filter_model->comparison){
                        case $filter_model::$EQUALS:
                            $subselect->where->equalTo('float_value', (float) $filter_model->float_value);
                            break;
                        case $filter_model::$GREATER_THAN:
                            $subselect->where->greaterThan('float_value', (float) $filter_model->float_value);
                            break;
                        case $filter_model::$LESS_THAN:
                            $subselect->where->lessThan('float_value', (float) $filter_model->float_value);
                            break;
                    }

                    $select->join(array(
                        'subselect'.$filter_array_count =>$subselect), 
                        'survey_responses.id = subselect'.$filter_array_count.'.response_id', 
                        array('float_value'));

                }
                $select->group('id');
                //$select->limit($limit);

                $adapterPlatform = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql();
                echo $select->getSqlString($adapterPlatform);
            });

    return $rowset;
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
       $subselect = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
                $subselect->from('question_responses');
                $subselect->where(array('question_id' => $filter_model->question_id));
                $subselect->where->lessThan('float_value', 2000);
                $select->join(array(
                    'subselect1' =>$subselect),
                        'survey_responses.id = subselect1.response_id',
                        array('float_value'));


                $subselect2 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
                $subselect2->from('question_responses');
                $subselect2->where(array('question_id' => $filter_model->question_id));
                $subselect2->where->greaterThan('float_value', 10);
                $select->join(array(
                    'subselect2' =>$subselect2),
                        'survey_responses.id = subselect2.response_id',
                        array('float_value'));
```

The $select->getSqlString($adapterPlatform); produces the desired query:

```
   SELECT `survey_responses`.*, `subselect1`.`float_value` AS `float_value`, `subselect2`.`float_value` AS `float_value` FROM `survey_responses` 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT `question_responses`.* FROM `question_responses` WHERE `question_id` = '11' AND `float_value` < '2000') 
   AS `subselect1` ON `survey_responses`.`id` = `subselect1`.`response_id` 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT `question_responses`.* FROM `question_responses` WHERE `question_id` = '11' AND `float_value` > '10') 
   AS `subselect2` ON `survey_responses`.`id` = `subselect2`.`response_id` GROUP BY `id`
```

However the query which is sent MYSQL and I have taken from the mysql logs is:

```
   SELECT `survey_responses`.*, `subselect1`.`subselect1`.`float_value` AS `subselect1.float_value`, `subselect2`.`subselect2`.`float_value` AS `subselect2.float_value` FROM `survey_responses` 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT `question_responses`.* FROM `question_responses` WHERE `question_id` = '11' AND `float_value` < '10') 
   AS `subselect1` ON `survey_responses`.`id` = `subselect1`.`response_id` 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT `question_responses`.* FROM `question_responses` WHERE `question_id` = '11' AND `float_value` > '10') 
   AS `subselect2` ON `survey_responses`.`id` = `subselect2`.`response_id` GROUP BY `id`
```

The difference being that the float_values in the second are now the same.

Can anyone shed any light on how these values could be correct for the getSqlString but wrong for the query send to mysql?

And how could I fix this issue, so mysql query has different float_values for each subselection.

Thanks

Abor.

Comment: This has been fixed in ZF2 2.3.1

Comment: It has indeed, thanks John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I found to create the subselections without them overwriting was to getSqlString for that subselection and concat them into the main query.

```
/**
 * get response by filter
 */
public function getResponsesByFilterArray($survey_id, $filter_array = NULL)
{
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->adapter;
    $platform = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql();

    $select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
    $select->from('survey_responses');
    $select_string = $select->getSqlString($platform);

    if($filter_array !== NULL)
    {
        $filter_array_count = 0;
        foreach($filter_array as $filter_model)
        {
            $filter_array_count++;

            $subselect = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
            $subselect->from('question_responses');
            $subselect->where(array('question_id' => $filter_model->question_id));

            switch($filter_model->comparison){
                case $filter_model::$EQUALS:
                    $subselect->where->equalTo('float_value', (float) $filter_model->to_value);
                    break;
                case $filter_model::$GREATER_THAN:
                    $subselect->where->greaterThan('float_value', (float) $filter_model->to_value);
                    break;
                case $filter_model::$LESS_THAN:
                    $subselect->where->lessThan('float_value', (float) $filter_model->to_value);
                    break;
                case $filter_model::$BETWEEN:
                    $subselect->where->between('float_value', (float) $filter_model->from_value , (float) $filter_model->to_value);
                    break;
            }

            $join_string = ' JOIN (%s) AS `%s` ON `survey_responses`.`id`  =  `%s`.`response_id` ';
            $sub_select_string = sprintf(
                $join_string, 
                $subselect->getSqlString($platform), 
                'subselect'.$filter_array_count,
                'subselect'.$filter_array_count
            );

            $select_string .= $sub_select_string;
        }
    }

    $where_string = ' WHERE `survey_id` = %s';
    $select_where_string = sprintf(
        $where_string,
        $survey_id
    );

    $select_string .=  $select_where_string;

    $sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($adapter);
    $rowset = $adapter->query($select_string, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

    return $rowset;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else,

Abor.